# history.js first step can't remind

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, history.js

I'm using history.js (https://github.com/browserstate/history.js - with the jQuery port) and I cant handle the "first step" (the origin one).
I.E. I'm from "/myPage", then I go to "/myPage/myContent2" and to "/myPage/myContent3" : it change, using AJAX, a part of the page. When I press the "previous" button, I come back to "/myPage/myContent2" and all is OK, but if I press it again, I'm back to "/myPage" (in adress bar) but my original content doesn't display :/. I've got an empty space in place of my content.

You could see live exemple here (it's not an Ad! But my online website - in french) : http://www.variance-auto.com/kits-film-teintes/vitre-teintee-Audi?choix_film=1 (that is equal to "/myPage")
Click one or more "modele" in the list on the left of the page.
In this live example I made a "hack" to avoid part of this problem : I double the first step using a "History.pushState" on the page load, that "save" the data of the first step. But you could see that you need two hit on the "previous" button to get back to the real previous page.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I did an article on this a couple of days a go.

Have a look at it and if you need any further assistance let me know, I'll do by best to help.

The URL is:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758486/Make-an-MVC-Application-into-a-SPA-with-AJAX-and-H

Comment: This would probably be better as a comment, currently. Links are certainly welcome, [but should still have an explanation along with them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259).